# NSView not receiving magnifyWithEvent:

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsevent

I've got a custom NSView and I want to receive the pinch to zoom event. I understand I've got to implement

```
-(void)magnifyWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event
```

But, I'm finding that my view is not receiving the event when I try and log it. The view is receiving other mouse events, such as scrollWheel: without a problem, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

In my project build settings the deployment target is set to 10.5, I'm not sure if that makes a difference, if so how would I capture this event while maintaining this deployment target?

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, are you testing on the simulator ? If yes, how are you performing the pinching action ? AFAIK, Accelerometer, Pinch events need to be tested on the device.

Comment: @Mahesh: You can execute a basic pinch/zoom gesture using a key combination in the simulator

Comment: I should of clarified, this is for a Mac OS X app, not a iPhone app.

Comment: What do you mean by `Mac OS X app` ? These are touch based events.

Comment: I thought touch based events were supported on 10.6 via the trackpad.

Comment: @Mahesh the `NSEvent` should have been a give away.

Comment: `-magnifyWithEvent:` and `NSEventTypeMagnify ` are Mac OS 10.6+ only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my silly mistake: I had the magnify gesture disabled in System Preferences. Doh!